Git interactive rebase in progress (постоянно всплывает)
Работаю с Git через Sublime Merge.
Проблема появилась в течении последних 10 дней. Когда точно не могу сказать. До появление проблемы все было ок. Т.е. это не новый проект, на котором внезапно при разворачивании\настройке что-то пошло не так.
Суть проблемы:
Когда добавлю последовательно несколько коммитов, а затем пробую их объединить (Edit Commit > Squash Selected Commits) выскакивает ошибка:

interactive rebase in progress; onto 1876cbdf Last commands done (2
commands done):    pick 0fe486a5     squash ecaf672a  No commands
remaining. You are currently rebasing branch 'personal_bonus' on
'1876cbdf'.   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
No changes You asked to amend the most recent commit, but doing so
would make it empty. You can repeat your command with --allow-empty,
or you can remove the commit entirely with "git reset HEAD^". Could
not apply ecaf672a...

Предлагает 2 решения: Abort rebase и Continue rebase
Соответственно при первом варианте объединение коммитов отменяется. При втором успешно проходит.
Но проблема в том, что если снова добавить еще несколько коммитов и попытаться их объединить - снова выскочит та же ошибка(независимо от предыдущего выбора).
Проблема наблюдается на разных ветках, но только на данном конкретном проекте.
Содержимое части файла git config:
[core]  
repositoryformatversion = 0  
fileMode = false  
bare = false 
logallrefupdates = true  
ignorecase = true  
eol = lf  
autocrlf = false

upd.
Если перед объединением коммитов прописать
git rebase --quit 

выдаст

fatal: No rebase in progress?

Но при попытке объединить коммитов проблема все равно появится
